# Sharing class variables in Python inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance

I am confused with variable sharing concept in Python in inheritance.

Consider the following code:-

```
class a(object):
    var1 = 0
    var2 = {}
    def print_var(self):
        print(self.var1)
        print(self.var2)

class b(a):
    @classmethod
    def modify_var(cls):
        cls.var1 = 1
        cls.var2['temp']="something"

o1 = a()
o2 = b()
print("Initial Values")
o1.print_var()
o2.print_var()
print("Changing Values")
o2.modify_var()
print("Print values after change")
o1.print_var()
o2.print_var()
```

After running above code I can see the dictionary is being shared between child and parent class, but integer variable isn't.

Can anyone please explain this, or what I am doing wrong here?

Output of above code:

```
Initial Values
0
{}
0
{}
Changing Values
Print values after change
0    # <- this zero should be one according to my understanding
{'temp': 'something'}
1
{'temp': 'something'}
```

Comment: The dictionary seems shared because you are not reassigning it. Try assigning it to a different dictionary. Inheritance of static/class variables will work as long as you don't reassign.

Comment: Sorry if i ask anything very basic.
I am relatively new to python.
Here I am modifying the variables.
Reassigning ... I am not getting whats that.

Comment: Don't be. It is a good question, and I don't think it is _very basic_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, you do not want to use mutable class variables.  A class variable is shared **by object reference** to all instances of the class.  But it is not shared across inherited classes.

So all instances of `a` share object references to `a.var1` and `a.var2`. Similarly, all instances of `b` share object references to `b.var1` and `b.var2`.  Upon creating the inheritance, `b` also get the references to `var1` and `var2`, but they are not shared back to `a` or any instantiations of `a`.

Because you use a **mutable** object for `var2`, the object's reference is never changed after the inheritance.  So you can modify `var2` and it will be modified for all references to it, because the object reference is the same.

If you reassign `var2` instead of modifying it, you get the expected behavior.

Try this:

```
class a(object):
    var1 = 0
    var2 = {}
    def print_var(self):
        print(self.var1, end=', ')
        print(self.var2)

class b(a):
    @classmethod
    def modify_var(cls):
        cls.var1 = 1
        cls.var2 = {'temp': 'something'}  # reassign to a new dict
```

Here are some tests:

```
ob1 = a()
ob2 = b()

o1.print_var()
o2.print_var()

o2.modify_var()

o1.print_var()
o2.print_var()

# prints
0, {}
0, {}
0, {}
1, {'temp': 'something'}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarification. So basically I should use class B's objects as I want variables to be shared among objects.

Comment: Correct.  If you need to share variables between objects of the same class, then a class variable is the right choice.  If you need to share variable between objects of multiple types, you make an additional class that is just a container for the instances of the objects you are using.